# How can I teleport every entity below Y=0 to Y=255 in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I teleport every entity below Y=0 to Y=255 in Minecraft? I'm making Skyblock, but I want falling out of the void to teleport you to the height limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken from [this post](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2950137-detecting-players-above-a-y-value?comment=2) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20191024083405/https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2950137-detecting-players-above-a-y-value)).

You can store all the player's y-level in a scoreboard:

```
/scorebaord objectives add dummy y
```

Then set the scoreboard values to the players' y-level (put this in a repeating command block):

```
execute as @a store result score @s y run data get entity @s Pos[1]
```

Finally, put this in another repeating command block to teleport the players to the height limit:

```
execute as @a[scores={y=..0}] at @s run tp @s ~ 255 ~
```